# How did Karna become the king of Anga?

Tags: karna

Karna was a son of a charioteer by his foster father and if I am not wrong he didn't fight with the previous king of Anga.

Comment: And what is your question? You didn't write your question in the body at all. Are you leaving comment in the body?

Answer (score 2):

When the Pandavas and Kauravas returned to Hastinapur after completing their education, they were showing their skills infront of the whole kingdom. When Arjun had almost defeated Duryodhan, Karna fired a bow from the crowd and saved Duryodhan and challenged Arjun. When he told his identity to everyone, he was refused to compete with Arjun as he was from a lower caste and son of a charioteer. Seeing this Duryodhan gifted him Anga Pradesh (so that he becomes a king and thus eligible to fight with Arjun).
Source: This is the conversation between Arjun and Karna can be found in the [Sambhav Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01139.htm)

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE! Please note that citing references is must here...you can cite references from [Sambhava Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01139.htm) in this post...